# My sql search syntax implementation

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I implement search function:

`where sub_menu_name like '%".$kws."%'`

into my working one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.sub_menu_id, p.sub_menu_name, m.image_id, i.file_url, m.default_menu_id, p.restaurant_id, p.status, p.sub_menu_price
FROM sub_sub_menu AS p
INNER JOIN menu AS m ON m.default_menu_id = p.sub_menu_id
                     OR m.id = p.sub_menu_id 
INNER JOIN icon AS i ON i.id = m.image_id
WHERE p.restaurant_id = '" . (int) $_SESSION['uid'] . "' "
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Add at the end `AND sub_menu_name like '%".$kws."%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.sub_menu_id, p.sub_menu_name, m.image_id, i.file_url, m.default_menu_id, p.restaurant_id, p.status, p.sub_menu_price
FROM sub_sub_menu AS p
INNER JOIN menu AS m ON m.default_menu_id = p.sub_menu_id
                     OR m.id = p.sub_menu_id 
INNER JOIN icon AS i ON i.id = m.image_id
WHERE p.restaurant_id = '" . (int) $_SESSION['uid'] . "'
AND sub_menu_name  LIKE '%".$kws."%'
```

I think this is what you want.

But I wonder why you have ". and ." before and after $kws. It's meant for concatenation so it won't work in SQL. If you want to check for $kws IN a value, the % % are enough.